# guzzle http buffer size or equivalent parameter

Tags: laravel, guzzle

i am re-factoring an old class to Laravel.

The old class use curl with an option

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 131072);
```

With Laravel i use GuzzleHttp\Client and i can't find any parameter for buffer size

Does anyone know how to set buffer size or any equivalent parameter to GuzzleHttp\Client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your custom curl options in guzzle, just use `curl` request option.

```
// $client : Your guzzlehttp instance
$client->request('GET', '/', [
    'curl' => [
        CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 131072
    ]
]);
```

You can also add it within guzzle instance.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['curl' => [\CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 131072]]);
```

Refer [Here](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-add-custom-curl-options)